# Apache Karaf 3rd party jar without bundle

Tags: java, jar, osgi, apache-karaf

I got a 3rd party jar which I am using for Blowfish decryption in a bundle that I need to deploy on apache karaf.

So now I also need karaf to know this jar but every solution I find is about creating a whole bundle for that jar which is pretty much for a simple library imo.

What I already did is installing that jar in my local maven repository and adding the dependency but this also doesn't work (at least on karaf).

Is there any other way to get 3rd party jars on apache karaf to work?

Comment: "So now I also need karaf to know this jar" -- What does this mean? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to use a 3rd party .jar in a bundle which is running on apache karaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addiction to @fiw you may want to osgify your thirdparty jar using Bndtools. In order to achive it:

1. [Download bnd tools](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/biz/aQute/bnd/bnd/2.4.0/bnd-2.4.0.jar)
2. Open a shell where you have downloaded bnd-2.4.0.jar.
3. Type:

   java -jar bnd-2.4.0.jar wrap -o osgify-dependency.jar dependency.jar

where *dependency.jar* is your third party and *osgify-dependency.jar* will be the output.

4. Deploy to maven repo overriding the previous maven coordinates, or deploy your thirdparty with different coordinates.

   mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile osgify-dependency.jar ...

Comment: If you install jpm from http://www.jpm4j.org then you can easily install bnd on the command line with `sudo jpm install -f bnd`

Comment: Good point!, thank you for the hint, I had never heard about that jpm4j but it seems cool.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a features xml file? If so you could use wrap:mvn: to make it available:

```
<feature name="feature1" version="1.0.0">
  <bundle>wrap:mvn:group.id/third.party.artefact.id/version</bundle>
  <bundle>mvn:group.id/your.artefact/version</bundle>
</feature>
```

This will bundle the third party jar at runtime and make sure it's installed for your bundle to use. Taken from [Karaf - Creating bundles](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/creating-bundles.html)

Comment: I addded it for my features.xml but in karaf when I try to install this feature I get 'Could not find artifact ... in central {http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/}' so it doesnt get it from my local repo

Comment: Does your config file etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.cfg have a property called org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories with a list of maven repositories in it? Also does that list contain your local maven repository e.g. file:/users/user/.m2/repository? From [Karaf Repo Resolution](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/urls.html)

Comment: it didn't contain my entry so I added it after the existing ones with a prepending '+' (+file://C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository) but still got the same problem

Comment: Repositories are comma separated, it may be something I don't know about but why do you think there is a need for a '+' there? What does your whole org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories look like?

Comment: Comment above the repositories: "To add repositories to the default ones, prepend '+' to the list of repositories to add." Looks like this now org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= [...] https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/@id=sonatype, \
 +file:C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository

Comment: To resolve this I would try a few things: try without the '+', make sure the path is correct, try with file://C:/, and put your local repo first in the list (it's used for resolution in order). Lastly you could use wrap:file: instead of wrap:mvn: in your features.xml and point straight to the jar, but ideally the maven protocol and local maven repository should work, it's just a case of getting the configuration right.